# NullReferenceException при обработке столкновения

Tags: c#, unity3d

При столкновении игрока с мобом, должно убавляться количество жизней, которое отображается в `LivesBar`, но вместо этого выдаёт ошибку:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Character.set_Lives (System.Int32 value) (at Assets/Scripts/Character.cs:16)
>   Character.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/Character.cs:60)

Скрипт противника:

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 7f;

    float direction = -1f;

    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(speed * direction, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(direction, 1, 1);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
            direction *= -1f;
    }

}
```

---

Скрипт Персонажа:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int lives = 5;

    public int Lives
    {
        get { return lives; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 5) lives = value;
            livesBar.Refresh();
        }
    }
    private LivesBar livesBar;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3.0F;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 15.0F;

    new private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        livesBar = FindObjectOfType<LivesBar>();
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) Run();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) Jump();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0F;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

     public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")

            Lives--;
    }
}
```

---

LivesBar:

```
public class LivesBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform[] hearts = new Transform[5];

    private Character character;

    private void awake()
    {
        character = FindObjectOfType<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
        {
            hearts[i] = transform.GetChild(i);
            Debug.Log(hearts[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i >= character.Lives)
            {
                hearts[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                hearts[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сиськи на 8 марта, это антифеминизм. Надо банить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `character` в `LivesBar` не инициализирован, т.к. `awake` не отрабатывает (описка в наименовании метода).

В скрипте `LivesBar` переименуйте `awake` в `Awake`.